# jquery jdialog non-modal

Tags: jquery, jdialog, non-modal

I am using sj:dialog to display some details of an user.
I need to make this into a non-modal window with minimize, maximize, close buttons.
Is it possible?

If not, then are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a jQuery modal window is not a modal window in the strict Windows sense of the word.  The jQuery UI modal window uses Javascript programming to make a section of a web page behave like a modal dialog as much as possible.

When you say that you would like for the modal to have minimize and maximize buttons, that doesn't really make sense because a jQuery UI modal cannot be "maximized" or "minimized" in a strict sense.  You could have it expand to take up the entire browser window.  That is certainly possible, but what could you possible mean by "minimizing" a jQuery dialog.  Where would it "minimize" to?